# Getting filename from filename

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I am using  `logger_example = inspect.stack()[1].filename`  to get my file name of where this code is being used in Python. However I am getting a full path name as "C:\Users\me\project\test_practice.py". I would like to know if there a way to get just the file name like test_practice from the returned logger_example. Does anyone have any ideas? I have tried multiple solutions but end up with unicode errors

Comment: is it possible to create another variable and use some functions to extract test_practice from the filename?

Comment: @tripleee: It's more than the duplicate, as *OP* also wants the extension removed.

Comment: `basename` does that too, but that information seems to be missing from the duplicate. Not to worry; I'll add an answer with that.